# Does anyone have a driver for Timelink Multitouch touch frame

Tags: drivers, multi-touch

Can anyone assist me please, i have a Timelink Multi-Touch frame that does not respond to any touch at all. I have tried downloading the touch driver from the manufacturers website "http://www.timelink.cn/index.php?m=content&oneid=369&id=385" but i have no idea how to install it.

When i run

```
usb-devices
```

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=04 Cnt=04 Dev#= 16 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2309 ProdID=1001 Rev=00.01
S:  Manufacturer=TimeLink
S:  Product=TimeLink MultiTouch
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=400mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

```
xinput
```

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ KYE Wireless keyboard and mouse Mouse     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ KYE Wireless keyboard and mouse Consumer Control  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TimeLink TimeLink MultiTouch              id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

```
lsb_release -a
```

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Can anyone help with getting this touch frame to respond to touch.

I'm using Ubuntu18.04.5, my Kernel version is 5.4.0-52-generic

Comment: reading the included readme file i am not sure that you are supposed to install it on modern linux, I would expect it to work plug and play....(though I understand that you have tried that..)

Comment: Which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]